# launch xxx.launch in catkin_ws

Tags: ros, launch, catkin

To start several nodes together, I write a launch file in catkin_ws. The first layer of my ws is: devel build src launch.
In src, I have several pkg, and each of them has a node.
However, I can only use cmd:

```
roslaunch start.launch
```

in `ws/launch`.

Can someone tell me if I want to use `roslaunch start.launch` in `ws/` , what I need to do?

I think if I put all nodes in one pkg and there is a launch directory in this pkg, I can "roslaunch" this launch file in workspace.
But it is not convenient to manage my code.

My launch file looks like this:
start.launch

```
 <launch>
    <node pkg="rslidar_sdk" name="rslidar_sdk_node" type="rslidar_sdk_node" output="screen">
    <param name="config_path" value=""/> 
   </node>
   <node pkg="cam_node" name="cam_node" type="cam_node" output="screen">
   <param name="config_path" value=""/>
   </node>
   <node pkg="imu_node" name="imu_node" type="imu_node" output="screen">
   <param name="config_path" value=""/>
   </node>
   <node pkg="lidarconv" name="lidarconv_node" type="lidarconv_node" output="screen">
   <param name="config_path" value=""/>
   </node>  
    <!-- rosrun rs_to_velodyne rs_to_velodyne XYZIRT XYZIRT -->
    </launch>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ROS`, it is very common to create your own custom package of launch files, i.e. containing just a `launch` folder containing just `.launch` files and with all its dependencies listed in the `CMakeLists.txt` file. Installing this package will also install the dependencies needed to start its launch files.

The project structure may look like this:

```
catkin_ws/
   devel/
   build/
   src/
      my_launch_pkg/
          launch/
              start.launch
          CMakeLists.txt
```

This way you just need to source your worskspace:

```
cd catkin_ws && source devel/setup.bash
```

to launch your launch file from anywhere:

```
roslaunch my_launch_pkg start.launch
```